# How to assert that collection is IReadOnlyCollection using NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a method in `SomeClass`, which return `IReadOnlyCollection`. 
Something like that:

```
public calss SomeClass
{
   private readonly List<Part> _parts;

   ...

   public IReadOnlyCollection<Part> GetAllParts =>
            this._parts;
}
```

In my Unit tests I want to assert that returned collection (`expectedCollection`) is IReadOnlyCollection.
I have tried with reflection:

```
[Test]
public void TestWariorsShoudReturnReadOnlyCollectionOfWariors()
{
    var expectedCollection = MyPartsLib.GetAllParts;

    Type type = expectedCollection.GetType();
    string acctualtypeName = type.Name;
    string expectedTypeName = "IReadOnlyCollection";
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedTypeName,acctualtypeName);
}
```

But `acctualtypeName` after executing is `` List`1 ``.
How can I assert that `expectedCollection` is `IReadOnlyCollection`?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#the-is-operator) for type checking

```cs
[Test]
public void TestWariorsShoudReturnReadOnlyCollectionOfWariors()
{
    var expectedCollection = MyPartsLib.GetAllParts;
    Assert.True(expectedCollection is IReadOnlyCollection<Part>);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```cs
...
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(expectedCollection, typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<Part>));
...
```

which results in a clear assertion message pointing out that the wrong type was retrieved.

Comment: You mean `Assert.IsInstanceOf<IReadOnlyCollection<Part>>(expectedCollection);` but yes it also works. Thank you!

Comment: Yes you are right. I fixed missing generic parameter.